# Bug: React.Component requires 1 argument but got 2

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript

Can someone help me resolve the following:

When creating a React.Component class I get the following error message:

**Code**:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

}
```

**Error**: Omitted certain things for brevity (see full error in image)

> Generic type '*$*$RsRpExt' from file '...\@types\react\index.d.ts, module=JavascriptReferencedFilesModules external files".React.Component requires 1 type argument(s) but got 2

[image: Error screenshot]

Inside the **index.d.ts** file:

```
 //
    // Component API
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    type ReactInstance = Component<any> | Element;

    // Base component for plain JS classes
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
    interface Component<P = {}, S = {}> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S> { }
    class Component<P, S> {
        constructor(props: P, context?: any);

        // We MUST keep setState() as a unified signature because it allows proper checking of the method return type.
        // See: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/18365#issuecomment-351013257
        // Also, the ` | S` allows intellisense to not be dumbisense
        setState<K extends keyof S>(
            state: ((prevState: Readonly<S>, props: P) => (Pick<S, K> | S)) | (Pick<S, K> | S),
            callback?: () => any
        ): void;

        forceUpdate(callBack?: () => any): void;
        render(): ReactNode;

        // React.Props<T> is now deprecated, which means that the `children`
        // property is not available on `P` by default, even though you can
        // always pass children as variadic arguments to `createElement`.
        // In the future, if we can define its call signature conditionally
        // on the existence of `children` in `P`, then we should remove this.
        props: Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }> & Readonly<P>;
        state: Readonly<S>;
        context: any;
        refs: {
            [key: string]: ReactInstance
        };
```

}

My **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
      "name": "timeregistration",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "./wwwroot/src/index.tsx",
      "dependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^16.0.31",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
        "typescript": "^2.6.2",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack",
        "watch": "webpack -w"
      },
      "author": "Jan Somers",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

Thank you :)